# How to distribute the file to the iphone devices? Warning "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your chain"

Tags: iphone, build, distribution, certificate, license-key

I am getting warning when installing the distributed build in the iphone as "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your chain" how can I generate a .p12 file.

After creating the .p12 file what are the steps to use that .p12 file.

I am trying it from 2 days how can i build the distributed file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is to export the private key from your Keychain & provide the same to the other machine where you are installing certificate & provisioning profile.

The details are mentioned here - http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action in the section "Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems"